# "plusDays" doesn't advance LocalDate in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

Why is `LocalDate` not changing even though there is no error during running?

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2005-12-12", formatter);
date.plusDays(3);
System.out.println(date.toString());
```

Output:

```
2005-12-12
```

Anything I missed out?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`LocalDate` is immutable

```
date = date.plusDays(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

As a `String`, it doesn't have an effect calling a method on it without assigning the result :

```
date = date.plusDays(3);
```

[Read More](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html)